# Search for filenames containing extended ascii characters

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression, ascii

I want to find all filenames in a directory tree that contain extended ASCII characters (0x80-0xFF).  I thought that I could do this like this:

```
find . -regex '.*[\x80-\xFF]+.*'
```

but instead it matches everything.  Alternatively I tried to look for files that contained any character not in a standard set of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, hyphen or period.

```
find . -regex '.*[^- a-zA-Z0-9]+.*'
```

Obviously I'm misunderstanding a fundamental aspect here.

Examples of the files in my tree:

```
./file 1/file - 1 - A2.mkv
./file 1/file - 1 - A2.nfo
./tést/tést - 2 - 2.mkv
./français/français - 2 -3.mkv
```

I'm using find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0, under Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The second regex matches the filenames with `français` and `tést` if you add `.` and `/` to the negated character class: `'.*[^- a-zA-Z0-9./]+.*'` (and you could remove the `+`).

Comment: @Freddy: That works, although I had to add a more lengthy list for my real world application.  But it's functional and gets me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tree
.
|-- file 1
|   |-- file - 1 - A2.mkv
|   `-- file - 1 - A2.nfo
|-- français
|   `-- français - 2 -3.mkv
`-- tést
    `-- tést - 2 - 2.mkv

3 directories, 4 files
```

```
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[![:print:]]*'
./tést
./tést/tést - 2 - 2.mkv
./français
./français/français - 2 -3.mkv
```

This set the locale for the `find` command to the standard POSIX locale.  The `print` character class contains characters that are part of the character classes `alpha`, `digit`, `punct`, and the space character is also included.  This means that the test `-name '*[![:print:]]*'` would be *true* for any filename that contains a character that is *not* in the `print` class.

If you want to not find names with various other space characters (tabs etc.), use `[![:graph:][:space:]]` as the test (the only difference between `print` and `graph` is that `graph` does not contain the space character).

Comment: I don't know if this is desirable for the OP or not, but this would also include ASCII filenames like that created by `touch $'\x01'`. Interesting to note that it prints it in the terminal as `./?`, but it actually writes the proper name when piped or redirected to a non-terminal, with GNU's `find`, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Kusalananda's answer also includes filenames with ASCII control characters. That may be desirable, but in case it's not, here's a solution based on Kusalananda's that more exactly answers the question:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name $'*[\x80-\xff]*'
```

Example use:

```
$ touch foo bár $'baz\x01'                         
$ ls
 bár  'baz'$'\001'   foo
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name $'*[\x80-\xff]*'           
./b??r
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name $'*[\x80-\xff]*' | od -tx1z
0000000 2e 2f 62 c3 a1 72 0a                             >./b..r.<
0000007
```

The difference with what you tried is that, here, the shell is the one interpreting the hex escape sequences instead of leaving it to `find`. Also, the `LC_ALL=C` is needed probably because otherwise `.` in regex or `*` in globs would match those bytes as part of other characters.